# MySql.Data.MySqlClient Error when calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql

I am running into an issue, that I believe lies within my privileges granted. However, I can't figure out why this is happening. I have a stored procedure in MySQL defined by:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure (var_one VARCHAR(20), var_two INT4)
BEGIN 
    UPDATE table_name SET ACTIVATION_DATE = UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 
    DEACTIVATION_DATE = TIMESTAMPADD(MONTH, var_two, UTC_TIMESTAMP()),
    USER_ACTIVATED = 1 WHERE ID = var_one;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I am calling this from my c# application. The code runs fine when I use userA's credentials. However, when I use userB it doesn't work. userA was granted privileges with the command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'userA'@'%';
```

userB was granted privileges with these commands:

```
GRANT UPDATE, SELECT ON current_db.table_im_updating TO 'userB'@'%';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure TO 'userB'@'%';
```

My code to call the mysql stored procedure is as follows:

```
connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=ip_address; port=3306; database=data_base; UID=userA; password=password; pooling=false");
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "my_stored_procedure";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id","associated_id");
command.Parameters["@_id"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subscription_length", "6");
command.Parameters["@subscription_length"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Like I mentioned. This code works fine when userA and userA's password are entered; but when I switch to userB the error says,

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

It is also worth noting that if I change my method of calling the procedure to this:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("CALL my_stored_procedure(var_one, var_two)", connection);
```

I get no errors. I am not trying to just make my code work, I want it to work properly. Please help me understand what is causing this Error. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated tips: when asking a question about an exception, always indicate which of the lines it occurred on. `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. `Input` is the default direction, so you don't need to specify that. Also, you may want to take a look at [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I started to use the .Add() function and defining the SQLDataTypes to avoid unwanted data loss using the .AddWithValue() function. I also appreciate the advice with making sure I properly handle unmanaged data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

userB should be granted with `SELECT` access to the `mysql.proc` table.

## Explaination

First, MySQL Connnector/NET is executed [`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE my_stored_procedure`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html) to get all parameters definition. (Order, Direction, DbType etc.)

Then, it will combine procedure name and parameters to create a sql like `CALL my_stored_procedure(var_one, var_two)` to execute.

> To use `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`, you must be the user named in the routine `DEFINER` clause or have `SELECT` access to the `mysql.proc` table. If you do not have privileges for the routine itself, the value displayed for the `Create Procedure` field will be **NULL**.
>
> -- [Doc: SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-procedure.html)
>   -- [Issue: Connector 8.0 - Stored Procedure Error in MySqlDataReader](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,665795,665805#msg-665805)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will update you after testing the changes.

Comment: I used GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO user. This cleared up my issue. I appreciate the help in figuring out my error.

Answer (score 0):

Give the userB the privileges to **Execute** the SP and add **CheckParameters=false** to Connection String

Comment: One thing to note if you add CheckParameters=false to the connection string, parameter names will be ignored and all params must be added to the command in the same order which the proc expects.